# Multi Line comments in Swagger

Tags: java, swagger

I'm new to Swagger.  Using Java.  I've inherited the app.  I see this import in the gradle file, so I assume I'm working with 3.0.0

implementation("io.springfox:springfox-boot-starter:3.0.0")

I need to dramatically upgrade the documentation of this app's API endpoints and that requires multi-line comments.

Is there a way to use Swagger annotations to have multi-line comments show up somewhere in the Swagger web page for the specific endpoint?  At this point, I'm not fussy about where the comments show up on the endpoint's section.

I've tried a few annotations, but Swagger is refusing to "respect" \n or \n\n and instead compresses everything and just wraps it which results in ugly and fairly unreadable documentation.

Based on what I read elsewhere, in at least some cases this is because of the type of HTML the annotation contents get turned into...

If there isn't a way to do this with Swagger annotations, is there another way?

Thanks.

Comment: if you're viewing it on a webpage, then this is what's supposed to happen. As per the HTML spec, `\n` gets treated as generic whitespace, unless you use CSS with an explicit `white-space: pre` to preserve things like newlines, tabs, and multiple spaces. That has nothing to do with Swagger or Java =) Of course, if your annotations target is explicitly HTML, nothing stopping you from adding `<br>` to control line breaks explicitly.

Comment: <br> doesn't work either I'm afraid.  Not in the  @ApiOperation "value" anyway...